# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when using ig.AnimationSheet

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I'm writing a game with impactjs right now and I have been struggling with this problem for awhile. In my player.js file I get a Uncaught TypeError when I try to initialize the animation sheet. The Error is located on the last line.

```
EntityPlayer = ig.Entity.extend({   
    size: {x:32,y:48},  
    health: 200,
    animSheet: new ig.AnimationSheet( 'media/player.png', 32 , 48 ),
```

My .requires looks like this:

```
.requires(  
    'impact.entity',    
    'impact.animation' 
 )
```

Since the constructor ig.AnimationSheet is the only function on that line, I would figure that it not being recognized. But this is confusing me because I though impact.animation was the correct location.

Comment: paste the entire js file to debug the real issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import `'impact.animation'` It's included in entity